# ComponentDidMount only fetching second data set

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch, state

I am trying to fetch two different tables for the same react component however I only seem to end up getting the most recent output. I believe it is because I have 2 separate ComponentDidMount components but I am unsure how to combined them. My code currently looks like this:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {items: [],locations: []}        
  } 
   
  componentDidMount() {
    fetch('/locationmenu')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(menu => this.setState({locations : menu}))}
  componentDidMount() {
    fetch('/clothesmenu')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(menu => this.setState({items : menu}))}
```

In this case only the /clothesmenu part of data seems to be added, and if I switch the two around only the /locationmenu is there.

Can anyone please tell me how to combine those componentDidMounts, or show me what I am missing elsewhere?

Comment: Only one definition sticks here. You're stomping your first version with your second.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use only 1 `componentDidMount` :

```
componentDidMount() {
    fetch('/locationmenu')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(menu => this.setState({locations : menu}));

    fetch('/clothesmenu')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(menu => this.setState({items : menu}));
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It was so simple, I can't believe I didn't try that! (although it was 1am when i hit this problem so tiredness probably didn't help)

Comment: you're welcome, you can do many stuff in the same lifecycle method, that's not a problem

Answer (score 2):

You can simply combine them in one single life cycle event:

```
componentDidMount() {
    fetch('/locationmenu')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(menu => this.setState({locations : menu}))}
    
    fetch('/clothesmenu')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(menu => this.setState({items : menu}))}
}
```